# How To Bind Google Visualization Data source Date values with Google Charts DateRangeFilter

Tags: javascript, java, json, google-visualization

I use REST services to fetch data into google charts.To create a chart supported json i used google visualization data source API to generate valid json obj.But the problem was that i can not create DateRangeFilter on my front view.Below is my sample code snippet.

**REST Service Code**

```
final DataTable data = new DataTable();
ArrayList<ColumnDescription> cl = new ArrayList<ColumnDescription>();
cl.add(new ColumnDescription("Time Stamp", ValueType.DATETIME, "Time Stamp"));

timeStamp = tr.getTimestamp().toString().trim();
dateTime = timeStamp.substring(0,timeStamp.indexOf(".")).replaceAll("-", "/");

for each(...){
data.addRowFromValues(dateTime );
}
```

**Js Code**

```
var dateSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
          'controlType': 'DateRangeFilter',
          'containerId': 'control_dateSlider',
          'options': {           
            'filterColumnLabel': 'Time Stamp',          
               'ui': {'labelStacking': 'vertical', 'label': 'Timeline :'}
          }
        });
```

**Sample Date Time value from DB**

```
12/5/2014 10:48:25 AM
```

Seems like the problem was on  **data.addRowFromValues(dateTime );**.Please can someone tell me that how can i pass valid date time value to google chart DateRangeFilter

Comment: why are you converting date to string. pass a date not a string.

Comment: yes i did that way also but nothing happen.and also google chart wants date format as 12-5-2014 instead of 12/5/2014. that's why i take it as string and replace.